# My multibit wallet (Ver. 0.5.15) shows nothing after being sent part of a coin?

Tags: wallet, multibit

I've reset the blockchain about 5 times over a week and still nothing

I upgraded multibit wallet to version 0.5.15 and still nothing.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!!! :-)

Comment: Do not vandalize your own posts.

Answer (score 1):

First, check on blockchain.info and see what the status of the transaction is.  Make sure that it shows that the address you think it was sent to really received the coins.  Once you have done that, you know that the transaction has been recorded publicly.  Then it is just a matter of opening a wallet that owns that address.

You need to check the "Request" tab in MultiBit and make sure that the address you sent the coin to is listed there.  If it isn't, then you have opened the wrong wallet, and you need to find the wallet that contains the address you sent it to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Harold! From this transaction http://blockexplorer.com/tx/5e4307b74042abca80b96d7fb1daca9ca14040ed9e2b1d36a9ecd6928be2635e#i58867693 with my multibit wallet address being 1HC9Tu1jpr9nztak4F5mr2zWyFfjaTiTjR do you think the part bitcoin should arrive into my wallet? Thanks again!

Comment: The balance of that address is zero:
http://blockexplorer.com/address/1HC9Tu1jpr9nztak4F5mr2zWyFfjaTiTjR

But you should check to see if you own any of the other addresses in your receive tab.